# Open image sent via Skype in the image tool directly?

Tags: 14.04, skype

Right now, Ubuntu does not support displaying images in Skype, but we see the link instead

[image]

As we cannot change this, is there a way that I click on the link and the local image app opens instead of the web browser?

Answer (score 0):

supposing you are using firefox on laptop/desktop

```
edit / preference / Application tab
```

look for `JPEG/...` and select `Use [...] Eye of gnome/mate`

sorry, I have no test image-link to try if it's ok